# How to add an HTML code to show a logo on the product image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a script from a price comparison website that I want to use on my woocommerce product page so that if my product price is cheaper on the price comparison website then a logo will appear on the product image as shown here:

[image]

The script that that I have received is like below and they told me to set this script for all product pages. The [article_number] should be replaced by woocommerce SKU. Can some one help me in adding this script in woocommerce to get the desired result? I guess I might need to call an action under functions.php of the child theme not not sure exactly which hook to call etc.

```
<a href="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=[article_number]&f=123456" target="_blank"><img src="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest.php?id=[article_number]&f=123456" /></a>
```

I tried the below code but its not working

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'cheap_logo', 5 );
  
    function cheap_logo() {
       global $product;
       $sku = $product->get_sku();
       echo '<ahref="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=$sku&f=123456"target="_blank"><img src="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest.php?id=$sku&f=123456" /></a>';
    
    }
```